# How can I store a value of 1000 over to EEPROM of Arduino Nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, eeprom

I need some of your feedback and guidance. In my prototype project powered by Arduino Nano(Space Constraint), it will operate continuously until it reach a maximum of 100 hours. Once it reached 100 hours mark, Nano will prompt users to do servicing/maintenance etc.

So in order to preserve the operating time from losing when powered off, I used EEPROM library to store the data. Based on my research, `EEPROM.update(addr,value)`, each `addr` can hold one byte, which is 0-255 values. To prevent my EEPROM die from storing operating time of 100 hours, I used *flag* method, where every 5 mins of operation it will increase *flag* and store the *flag* value to EEPROM.

Is there other method other than changing the `5 mins` benchmark?

Below is the simple/direct code that I wrote, the original code is too complex, and I have put a few comment especially the `"Ideal Command"` that I want.

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  regenflag=EEPROM.read(regenaddr);
}

void loop()
{
regenflag=EEPROM.read(regenaddr);

if(totaltime>=300000)//Every 5min machine operated, increase regenflag (Fixed)
  {
    regenflag=regenflag+1;
    Serial.print("How many times it Operated==> ");
    Serial.println(regenflag);
    unblink=1;//Flag for other operation

    EEPROM.update(regenaddr,regenflag);
    regendata=EEPROM.read(regenaddr);

    totaltime=0;
}

/////////////////////////////////Ideal Command/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (regendata>=1200) //100hrs=6000mins (6000mins/5mins=1200 times)
{
  Serial.println("Need to do Servicing")
}
```

Comment: use EEPROM.put and EEPROM.get https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMPut